# Activity Stack or fragments?

Tags: android

I am new to Android development - I have been doing iOS for a while. I would like to mimic the NavigationController.PushViewController(...) used in iOS. I understand that fragments can be used to do this? It also seems that starting an Activity from within an activity is doing exactly this already (minus some animations). Which is the 'correct' way to do this? My app is simple - a list of 'drinks' - tap one and see the ingredients... That's it, simple as pie.

Answer (score 1):

Either or really. I think as a beginner pushing and popping Activities will be easier to learn, although Google is really promoting Fragments as the new standard

Start with Activities, then move to Fragments

Answer (score 1):

Fragments should be used if you want to take out only part of your UI-  lets say you have a left pane, a right pane, and a bottom pane-  use fragments if you want to change one out without touching the other two.  If you're switching between full screen workflows, use activities.